# Libgdx - game behaving weird on SOME devices

Tags: android, libgdx

My app [Square Smash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olvins.squaresmash), I am linking this if there is someone who wanna try if the game works fine.

I made the Game Screen with

```
static int WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()
static int HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

and then just made everything to be a % of the screen.

The other screens were made with Viewports, because I did not know about them when I started making the game. The weird part is the game works fine on most devices.

First... In the game you have falling roses and squares and you have to click squares to score points. But... I tried it on LG G3 and the hit boxes were totally fail. You have to click like on a totally different coordinate. When I tested it on my 5 phones the hit boxes were totally different also. Like somewhere the hit box was lower, somewhere it was more to the right and somewhere it was on a totally different place.

If you're asking why I would release such a game it is because I used 4 SIMULATORS with different resolutions and it worked like a charm there.

So what, why would it behave for a device different?

The code (it's a total mess but you should see the clear points, there are some variables that are useless, cause I kept chaging the code alot, but did not bother deleting): http://pastebin.com/f9SKhcMb
Also the code for falling shapes: http://pastebin.com/Q1XFGeWE

Comment: It looks like you didn't implement the resize method and aren't unprojecting input coordinates (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems). Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and create a mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I don't use the resize method because I have no Viewports, it is all handled manually. For screen Height I just use Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY. The weirdest thing of all is that I use the same coordinates for the Textures and the collision circle around them and yet still collision is somewhere else depending on the device. Although on my phone or EMULATORS it works fantastic!

Comment: Well if you really want to handle it manually then you should handle the resize and unprojecting manually as well. I searched your code for `Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY` and found 0 results. it does contain something like `R_HEIGHT - screenY`, but R_HEIGHT is a static and not updated on resize.

Comment: I now update R_HEIGHT and R_WIDTH in resize and still the same. Although I don't know why I would even need that considering R_HEIGHT and R_WIDTH for that screen is always the same. I am going to refactor the code to use a viewport, because that will work for sure.